# How to determine if a propositional formula is in DNF or CNF or both

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form, disjunctive-normal-form

How can I determine if a propositional formula is in *DNF* or *CNF* or *both*. What conditions must a propositional formula satisfy?

For example, why is $(a \land b)$ both in *CNF* **and** *DNF*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is $DNF$ because it can be seen as 
$$
... \text{nothing} \vee (a \wedge b) \vee \text{nothing}...
$$
And $CNF$ :
$$
 (...\text{nothing} \vee a \vee \text{nothing}...) \wedge (...\text{nothing} \vee b \vee \text{nothing}...)
$$
By $nothing$ I don't mean something always true or false (even thought it can be thought of $\bot$) but simply there is nothing, no character.

Comment: For the  `DNF`, does `...nothing`, `a` and `b` (and so on) represent conjunctive clauses?

Comment: The classical form of DNF is $(var_1\ \vee ... \vee\ var_n) \wedge\ ... \ (...)\ ...\ \wedge(var_\alpha\ \vee ... \vee\ var_\omega)$ so $a$ and $b$ represent boolean variables which can be of any number in any clauses. A clause may contain any number of variables separated by $\wedge$. So every "parenthesis-group" is a conjonctive clause.

Comment: You are switching the names. The first formula in your answer is in DNF and the second is in CNF. And instead of `nothing`, you could have used `false`.